# Does Apache or WiFi change when macbook is on battery?

Tags: macos, wireless-networking, battery

I haven't dug too deep into the answer, but it seems like something disconnects when I run on battery mode. The page (at 192.168.1.103) still runs ok on the laptop, but the iPad next to it <strike>invariably</strike> seems to often give 'server not responding' until I plug the laptop power back in.

So maybe it isn't Apache, but the WiFi?

The sleep timer is set to 1hr on battery, 'never' on powered.

I just looked at this question:

[MacBook wifi gets unreliable/slow when NOT charging](https://superuser.com/questions/21513/macbook-wifi-gets-unreliable-slow-when-not-charging)

I am on 10.6.8. Is that WiFi problem still an issue?

Comment: If `192.168.1.103` is the laptop itself, it should always work on the laptop. Do you have another computer to test it on? I don't know if iOS has a `ping` or similar tool.

Comment: I am trying to get it to fail again. It might be some quirk on the iPad. Another mac on the lan gets it so far.

Comment: update.. left it 'till screen dimmed, tried connection (a big fat POST), timed out. Plugged it in, page served!

Comment: Is the iPad connected to the Mac via Dock connector?

Comment: Havn't docked it for ages. But it was fired up (is that the term? Associated with an iTunes on that computer) from the laptop serving the web page. Otherwise, the iPads only wire to the rest of the world is for power, and over WiFi.